# Where do they create the circle that appears in the tooltip with the tooltipServiceWrapper for Power BI custom visuals?

Tags: typescript, powerbi

I'm curious where the circle is created for the tooltip. I know where to change the color for the circle (i.e., in the `color:...` line below), but I was hoping I might be able to change the circle, itself, to other symbols.

```
    private static getTooltipData(value: any): VisualTooltipDataItem[] {
        return [
            {
                displayName: 'Project: ',
                value: value.project,
                header: " ",
                color: buildcolor(value.component)
            },
       ];
    }
```

Comment: Did you happen to find the answer to this? I am trying to change the circle into a rectangle but cant seem to find where this happens...

Comment: Unfortunately, no.